# Find how an element's css has changed after jQuery "toggle" function has been used

Tags: jquery, css

I am using `toggle()` in my Javascript function to change the CSS class of an element. When the element is clicked on, the class is removed, when it is clicked on again the class is added again. How can I find out whether the `toggle()` function is adding or removing the class from the element so that I can perform some other operations based on that?

Comment: Look at `hasClass` function.

Comment: you could also use a selector based on the class.

Comment: can u provide an example for me

Comment: @PSR I made quite a big edit to your question to try and make it clearer so if other people search for the same thing it will be easy to find and because I don't feel it should be closed. I hope I have understood properly and my edit still describes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [is method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to determine whether the element meets the appropriate selector (in this instance a class selector):

```
if (element.is('.class'))...
```

Comment: is it is() class hasClass() ??

Answer (score 3):

You can use hasClass() to check if the element has that class, if true it was just added if false it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

here is raw example

```
  $('#test').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
        $(this).toggleClass('blue');

        if($(this).hasClass('red')) {alert('red');}
        if($(this).hasClass('blue')) {alert('blue');}
    });
```